# How can I find the location of settings files for User/Workspace/Folder scopes in an extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there a way to find location of settings file for User / Workspace / Folder scopes from an extension?
This is not to update the settings, but the extension I am working on just needs location of these files to show to user.

Comment: Are you going to open those folder locations?  Or just show the locations?

Comment: I just need to show the locations in a UI to the user. All settings locations for User/Workspace/Folder scopes.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [`workspace`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#workspace) object's `workspaceFolders` field and take the `uri` field of each [`WorkspaceFolder`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#WorkspaceFolder). You'll get a [`Uri`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Uri) object from which you can take the `path` field and then just resolve the relative path `.vscode/settings.json` with respect to the workspace folder path. If needed, make sure to check that a file exists at that path (one might not if the user didn't create one).

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. Same way, is there a way to find user settings file? In my windows machine, it is at <user dir>\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json

Answer (score 0):

For user settings try this:

```js
const path = require('path');

const userSettingsPath = path.join(process.env.APPDATA, "Code/User/settings.json");

// const userSettingsPath = path.join(process.env.APPDATA, "Code - Insiders/User/settings.json");
```

That last version is if they are using the Insiders Build, which you can check with

```js
vscode.env.appName  // Visual Studio Code or Visual Studio Code - Insiders
```

---

For workspace settings ( as @user suggested), this code works:

```js
  const ws = vscode.workspace.asRelativePath(context.extensionUri);
  const workspaceSettings = path.join(ws, ".vscode/settings.json");
```

BUT, the user might have a multiroot workspace open and so you would have to look at `vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders` for all workspaceFolders and if there is a `.vscode/settings.json` in any of them.

---

And there might be issues if they are connected to remotely or to the web.  Here are a couple of links about the settings locations: [Setting file locations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations) and [remote extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/remote-extensions)

Comment: Thanks @Mark. 

Location of user settings file is different in different OS.  

Depending on your platform, the user settings file is located here:

Windows %APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json
macOS $HOME/Library/Application\ Support/Code/User/settings.json
Linux $HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json

Will process.env.APPDATA work for macOS and Linux also?

Comment: `process.env.OS` and `process.env.HomePath` please try those on the other platforms if, in your testing `process.env.APPDATA` doesn't work on all platforms.